# Changing personal site configuration with jekyll

Tags: jekyll, minima

I'm trying to build [a site](https://rjraya.github.io/)  with jekyll. I managed to make math work and upload some files. Now the overall distribution of content is not optimal.

- I get a link to "HEAD" that lists a series of updates of Jekyll. I would like to get rid of that.
- The main url redirects to some blog entries while you have to click on "About" in order to go to some general information about me. I would like to do it in the opposite way, i.e. having the about section shown in the main url of the page https://rjraya.github.io/ and the blog in some derived url like https://rjraya.github.io/blog

[Here](https://github.com/rjraya/rjraya.github.io) are the sources of the page. How can I do this simple changes? I understand that I'm using the Minima template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Re: HEAD

I think the "HEAD" is coming from the `History.markdown` file.  It is strange that the "HEAD" does not show up in a local `jekyll serve` development environment.  I suspect the [code below](https://github.com/rjraya/rjraya.github.io/blob/ddc6a2f5c5804961da6ac79472b7f77052bef267/_includes/header.html#L20-L27) is picking up `History.markdown` in `jekyll`, along with `about.md` when rendering `header.html`.

https://github.com/rjraya/rjraya.github.io/blob/ddc6a2f5c5804961da6ac79472b7f77052bef267/_includes/header.html#L20-L27

```
    <div class="trigger">
      {%- for path in page_paths -%}
        {%- assign my_page = site.pages | where: "path", path | first -%}
        {%- if my_page.title -%}
        <a class="page-link" href="{{ my_page.url | relative_url }}">{{ my_page.title | escape }}</a>
        {%- endif -%}
      {%- endfor -%}
    </div>
```

## RE: Page Title URL `Computational reflections`

Change the `href` from `/` to `/blog` in this line
https://github.com/rjraya/rjraya.github.io/blob/ddc6a2f5c5804961da6ac79472b7f77052bef267/_includes/header.html#L7

```
<a class="site-title" rel="author" href="{{ "/blog" | relative_url }}">{{ site.title | escape }}</a>
```

## RE: About URL

Remove the `permalink : /about/` from the `about.md` page.  The `about.md` will be come the homepage (e.g. `/`) in the next step.
https://github.com/rjraya/rjraya.github.io/blob/gh-pages/about.md

## RE: Show `about.md` information on homepage `rjraya.github.io` and show `_posts` markdown files under `rjraya.github.io/blog`

Let `jekyll` use the default behavior of assigning permalinks based on the markdown filename.

Rename `index.md` to `blog.md`.  This will move the list of `_posts` files from `/` to `/blog`.

Rename `about.md` to `index.md`.  This will move the content of `about.md` from `/about` to `/`.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot, I will try it and accept if it works

Comment: Sorry with that configuration I don't get what I want. I get the blog in the main url, while what I would like to get is the about section.

Comment: @Rodrigo, I may have misunderstood your requirements.  For the main url, you want the link to go to the `about.md`.  What about the about link, where would you like for that to go?

Comment: So essentially I would like the https://rjraya.github.io/ to redirect to the contents in about.md and the link https://rjraya.github.io/blog to redirect to the content in _posts, i.e. what is shown in https://rjraya.github.io/ now.

Comment: Oh, I think what you want is for https://rjraya.github.io/ to show `about.md` and for `https://rjraya.github.io/blog` to show your list of `*.md` files under `_posts` directory.  ~~Correct?~~ edit: I see you just answered :)

Comment: exactly, that's what i wanted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230949/discussion-between-kin-and-rodrigo).